# postgres add value to an existing column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this for example:
 
id, first_name, last_name   
1, James, Anderson 
2, William, Davis 
3, Ethan, Walsh

I would like to add a prefix to their first names, 
So it will looks like this:

id, first_name, last_name  
 
1, EXT-James, Anderson   
2, EXT-William, Davis    
3, EXT-Ethan, Walsh

So basically I want to add the value 'EXT-' to the first_name column
Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update the_table
  set first_name = 'EXT-'||first_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'EXT-' || first_name FROM YourTable
```